# Multilevel Combo box in vb6

Tags: vba, vb6

I am trying to create a multilevel combobox in vb6 similar to that seen in the attached image. This box will be used to select values and then save same to an access database (any insights into how I would design this aspect of the database is welcomed) an. I have been searching for a method to do this, but I have not found any up to this point. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a `Popup menu` that was bounded to the `ComboBox` click event

[This link](http://www.vbrad.com/article.aspx?id=3) demonstrates how to create a popup menu programmatically

And If you're working with VB6, just hit CTR+E, and follow [these instructions](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/working-menus-vb6)

After configuring the Popup menu, all you're left to do is:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Call popupMenu.ShowPopupMenu
End Sub
```

And make sure all the menu functions sets the `Text` property of of `ComboBox1`